# Selected Value in Multi-Column ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a table named Groups in my Database as follows:

```
Groups
  |--GroupID
  |--GroupName
  |--ParentID
  |--NatureOfGroupID
  |--EffectID
```

Here is the relationship diagram for above table:

[image]

I have a combobox in a window in which I have two columns. Here is the xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding ParentID}" SelectedValuePath="GroupID">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" Width="200" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CorrespondingEffect}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Actually i want to show GroupName and its corresponding Effect but when user selects any Item then I want to get SelectedValue as ParentID.

Here is the implementation of GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect.cs

```
public class GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect : MainViewModel
{
    private string _groupName;
    public string GroupName 
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupName;
        }
        set
        {
            _groupName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupName");
        }
    }

    private string _correspondingEffect;
    public string CorrespondingEffect 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return _correspondingEffect;
        } 

        set 
        {
            _correspondingEffect = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CorrespondingEffect");
        } 
    }
}
```

Here is the code for groupsViewModel.cs

```
public class GroupsViewModel : MainViewModel
{
    public GroupsViewModel()
    {

        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects = (from g in db.Groups
                                                  select new GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect
                                                  {
                                                      GroupName = g.GroupName,
                                                      CorrespondingEffect = g.Master_Effects.Effect
                                                  }).ToList();

            NaturesOfGroup = (from m in db.Master_NatureOfGroup
                              select m).ToList();
        }

        SaveChangesCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveGroup);

        CurrentGroup = new Group();
    }

    private Group _currentGroup;
    public Group CurrentGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentGroup;
        }

        set
        {
            _currentGroup = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentGroup");
        }
    }

    private List<GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect> _groupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects;
    public List<GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect> GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects;
        }
        set
        {
            _groupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects");
        }
    }

    private List<Master_NatureOfGroup> _naturesOfGroup;
    public List<Master_NatureOfGroup> NaturesOfGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return _naturesOfGroup;
        }
        set
        {
            _naturesOfGroup = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NaturesOfGroup");
        }
    }

    public ICommand SaveChangesCommand { get; set; }

    private void SaveGroup(object obj)
    {
        Group cGroup = new Group()
        {
            GroupName = CurrentGroup.GroupName,
            **ParentID = CurrentGroup.ParentID,**
            NatureOfGroupID = CurrentGroup.NatureOfGroupID,
            EffectID = CurrentGroup.EffectID
        };

        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            db.Groups.Add(cGroup);
            db.SaveChanges();

            GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects = (from g in db.Groups
                                                  select new GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect
                                                  {
                                                      GroupName = g.GroupName,
                                                      CorrespondingEffect = g.Master_Effects.Effect
                                                  }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

When I debug and put a breakpoint on the line marked with ** .... ** I always get CurrentGroup.ParentID = null.

**Update:**

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:GroupsViewModel />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding CurrentGroup}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.6*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.6*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text=" : " HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding GroupName}"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="Under" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text=" : " HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbUnder" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding ParentID}" SelectedValuePath="GroupID">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" Width="200" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CorrespondingEffect}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="Nature of Group" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=cbNature}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text=" : " HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=cbNature}"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbNature" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Visibility="{Binding SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource selectedIndexToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=cbUnder}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.NaturesOfGroup, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" DisplayMemberPath="Nature"
              SelectedValue="{Binding NatureOfGroupID}" SelectedValuePath="NatureOfGroupID"/>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="4" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding DataContext.SaveChangesCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: `CurrentGroup` is nowhere binded from XAML. Where are you setting this?

Comment: CurrentGroup is bound to Grid which is parent of Combobox. Sorry I forgot to mention that in question.

Comment: Bound to Grid means? How does that gets updated? Grid doesn't have any SelectedValue property. How does that gets in sync with combobox selected value?

Comment: Please see Update in my question to better understand about binding between Grid and CurrentGroup.

Comment: Please see at very bottom of the question. The updated xaml where I mentioned that `<Grid DataContext="CurrentGroup">.......`And in C# just below the line you mentioned I declared `public Group CurrentGroup`. Here datatype of CurrentGroup is Group, so I think it should set actual properties automatically. And if I am doing some mistake than give me a little demo example to understand.

Comment: Please check my answer. I can see two issues in your current approach. Try rectifying them and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two issues in your code.

**First** of all you mentioned

> Actually i want to show GroupName and its corresponding Effect but
>   when user selects any Item then I want to get SelectedValue as
>   ParentID.

But in combobox declaration, you set `SelectedValuePath="GroupID"`. It should be set to ParentID - `SelectedValuePath="ParentID"`.

---

**Second**, even if you set `SelectedValuePath` to `ParentID`, it won't work since combobox ItemsSource is a list of `GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect`  which doesn't have any property `ParentID` in it.

For SelectedValuePath to work underlying model class should have that property, so create a property and filled it from database like other two properties.

```
GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects = (from g in db.Groups
                             select new GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect
                             {
                                GroupName = g.GroupName,
                                CorrespondingEffect = g.Master_Effects.Effect,
                                ParentID = g.ParentId
                             }).ToList();
```

So, for your solution to work, you have to fix both these issues.

Comment: I have some problem with your first solution: If I set SelectedValuePath="ParentID" then what value should I set for SelectedValue?

Comment: This is same what you did for second combobox `SelectedValue="{Binding NatureOfGroupID}" SelectedValuePath="NatureOfGroupID"`. Now to clarify `SelectedValue` points to actual property instance where you want to keep track of selected object in combobox and `SelectedValuePath` means in case an object is binded to object then which property should serve as path for selectedValue. So, in your case both will be `ParentID` just like you have done for second combobox.

Comment: I have tried your second solution and also read your above comment and made the changes as you suggested but now I always `CurrentGroup.ParentID = 1`

Comment: Place the breakpoint on setter of ParentID property and see the value that is passed to it via comboBox. Also have you make sure when you filling `GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects` property all values have unique ParentID? And by second solution you meant? I posted only one solution with two issues. You need to fix both.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have got it. I mis-understood the concept. I needed GroupID not ParentID. But I have solved it the same way you suggested in your answer. Thank you once again for helping me and giving me your time.